# Username mod rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I need help with mod rewrite ...I'm trying to change

```
domain.com/user.php?username=foo
```

to

```
domain.com/foo
```

My current rewrite is:

```
RewriteRule username/(.*)/ user.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule username/(.*) user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

which outputs

```
domain.com/username/foo
```

but i'm not happy with that.

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ user.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) user.php?username=$1 [L]
```

This will send every request to user.php. If you don't want that it's probably better to send everything to a php routing script that can handle things a bit better e.g.,

```
# if the requested file exists (e.g., css, javascript) then serve it up 
# otherwise send to router.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php [L]
```

Then in router you can get the path from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` e.g.,

```
$urlparts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$path = explode('/', $urlparts['path']);

if(isUser($path[0])) {
    $_GET['username'] = $path[0];
    include 'user.php';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule (.*) user.php?username=$1 [L]
```