# Pages redirect (User friendly URL's)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, get

How would I display dynamic content, say profile pages with the url syntax

> mysite.com/users/user1
>   mysite.com/users/user2
>   mysite.com/users/user3

Without having a different page or directory for every user. I'm hoping there is a way to just have something like an index.php file in the users directory and have it display appropriate user content based on the user1, user2, user3 part of the url.

I know this is common but I'm not sure how to do it or what ever it would be called to google it?

Comment: You are looking for url rewriting. There are loads of examples here in SO.

Comment: would that be via .htaccess?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Username mod rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124269/username-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your running apache, you may want to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rules for your .htaccess file.

In the following example, I redirect anything that is pointing to `/users/user*` to a file in the root of the site called `users.php`. You notice the `([^/\.]+)`. This is a "catch-all" reg-ex that will allow me to create a variable for my query string (ex: `?id=$1`).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^users/user([^/\.]+) users.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then in my `users.php` i can retrieve the variable as:

`$id = $_GET['id']`

This will allow me to catch and handle all user URLs with only 1 file.

**Note:** This is only an example. It will have to be built upon but it could be a good starting point for you